# Check if a user input has https and include it if it doesn't

Tags: python

I've been developing a webscrapper to a certain website and my goal is to let users just input the link of a page of this website to return some information.

Sometimes, users will copy/paste the link without "https://" and my app returns an error.

So, I tought this to avoid the error:

```
url = input("Your link")

if 'https://' in url:
  url
else:
  url = 'https://'+url
```

It works, but I wonder if it is the best solution to check just the https part.

Also, how could I check if it's including a valid link? Like, check if the link starts with https:// certaindomain

Comment: What if they use http:// instead of https://

Comment: My first attempt was too simplistic indeed. That's why I wonder if that are better ways to do it.

Comment: `if not url.startswith('https://): url = f'https://{url}'`

Comment: what do you mean by a valid link? if it "exist" (syntactically valid string) or if you can connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib.parse.urlparse()` using `.scheme` to get whether the URL is over HTTPS, and using `netloc` to determine whether the website name is correct.

It's not immediately clear what output you're expecting for URLs that don't use HTTPS, so this code snippet is mostly to demonstrate how to get the scheme, and I'll let you customize the error handling to your own situation:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = input("Your link")

parse_result = urlparse(url)

print(parse_result.scheme)
print(parse_result.netloc)
```

If you pass in:

```
https://github.com/
```

The program will output:

```
https
github.com
```

Comment: In this case, if the users type a url without 'https://', it doesn't print nothing. After check the condition, I need to 'send' this URL to my program to do the webscraping part. And / or ask the user to verify/change the link that he/she is pasting when the conditions are not met.